# What are the differences with the code below?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a few pieces of code and I've got some questions

```
def fanction(tata):
    for i in range(0,4):
        tata +i
        print tata

tata = 0
fanction(tata)
```

The results are

```
0
0
0
0
```

Second piece of code :

```
def fbnction(tbtb):
    for i in range(0,4):
        print tbtb +i

tbtb = 0
fbnction(tbtb)
```

The results are

```
0
1
2
3
```

Third piece of code :

```
def fcnction(tctc):
    for i in range(0,4):
        print tctc, tctc +i

tctc = 0
fcnction(tctc)
```

The results are

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
```

Can someone give some explanation on the why, please of having different results? I thought it would give me the same results all the time.

Comment: I did not make myself clear. How come the third piece of code is incrementing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tata + i` does not change `tata`. It just returns added value.

If you want `tata` to be changed, you need to assign back the added result.

```
tata = tata + i
```

or

```
tata += i
```

---

```
>>> tata = 5
>>> i = 2
>>> tata + i
7
>>> tata  # not changed
5
>>> tata = tata + i
>>> tata  # changed
7
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first piece and third piece of code tata +i will not impact on tata. so you need to assign the added value in the variable to get the same result

```
tata = tata + i
```